# Directing to right form based on whcih button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to use the MEAN stack for the following assignment.

- I have created several registration forms which work fine. One registration page is index.html(which through Angular loads several views/tabs within it, so they are multi-paged) and another one, index2.html.

  - There is also a main webpage that I have created which is a simple page that
    has the company's logo, name and two buttons.
- Clicking on each button will direct you to a different registration
  form(either index.html or index2.html).
  This last functionality is where I am having problems. How do I connect the main page to the different registration forms? In other words, how do I redirect the user to the right registration page when they click the corresponding buttons? Should I use node to route to the correct registration page or use Angular Route? As you can see, currently I am attempting to use Angular Route but am unsure if that is the right tool for this purpose. Any help and direction would be greatly appreciated.
  Thank you

Here is the code that I have for the main page(home.html):

```
<html ng-app="myHome">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/redirect.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script><!--This is to call Angular JS-->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/redirect.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="rotate">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <img src="/css/Logo_75.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WHAT TYPE OF QUOTE ARE YOU REQUESTING:</h1><br>
                <h1>DIGITAL OR SCREEN QUOTE?</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/digital">DIGITAL QUOTE</a></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><a href="#/screen">SCREEN QUOTE</a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This is the angular JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('myHome', [ngRoute]);

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/digital', {
            templateUrl: '/index.html'
        }).
        when('/screen', {
            templateUrl: '/index2.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home.html'
        });
}]);
```

where index.html is the registration form for the "digital" option and index2.html is the registration form for the "screen" option. If anyone needs to see the code for those registration forms, please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ng-view directive.
Change your container to look like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Place the content you had in there into template index.html and rename your index.html to digital.html and index2.html to screen.html to correspond with route names (well it's a recommendation since it makes a lot of sense I believe)

And change the routing to this

```
var app = angular.module('myHome', [ngRoute]); 
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: '/index.html' })
        .when('/digital', { templateUrl: '/digital.html' })
        .when('/screen', { templateUrl: '/screen.html' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }); 
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Molda!